# get image from database and put it into on html in div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I fetched the image from database and want to put this image inside or fit in the div tag without stretching the images. All images are of different size so I cannot use `width` and `height` for image properties because when I use it then the image is stretching.

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px;">
     <img src="link.jpg" alt="jet">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this css

```
 img {
     max-width:100%
 }
```

[**EXAMPLES**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/UyQp2/1/)

You have these two options if you cant get the image in proper size you want, keep in mind re-sizing the image in browser leads to performance issues.

Comment: cant used width:100%; because all images are different size and i want to keep all the image as same ration(dimension without stretching the image).

Comment: only specifying with will maintain the aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

Try this: set `max-width` for image and `width` to auto.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
     <img src="link.jpg" alt="jet">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img 
{ 
  width:auto; 
  max-width:300px;
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mw9YS/1/)**.

It should work!
Thanks

Comment: But what if `height` of `img` is 1000px? It won't fit in `div` as the `height` of div should be 300px.

Comment: we just need to adjust `width` for img, no need to set height. It'll auto to `width`.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

```
img
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the widht and height in the image tag but use css something like this:

For constant width of max 300px and variable height:

```
img {
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* needed for some browsers to keep the proportions */
}
```

For constant *height* of max 300px and variable *width*:

```
img {
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto; /* needed for some browsers to keep the proportions */
}
```

If you want the image to fit the container (no larger than the containers width or height) and scale proportionally, you can use:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto; /* optional, to center horizontally/vertically */
}
```

This will make the image maximally 300px wide/tall and undistorted and no larger than the container.